# Uninstalling Ubuntu for a fresh start

Tags: uninstall

After failing countless times to install ubuntu to dual boot with windows 7, I decided to try to get rid of all things ubuntu and try again. There is no partition in my hard drive that I can find at this point, but when I go to re-install Ubuntu it says that I already have 2 OSes installed, and I can't use the normal install alongside option. Is there anything I am missing that is making it think there is something left?

Answer (score 1):

Windows can’t read Ubuntu partition, so you can’t see it on Windows. When you have 2 OS’s there should be an **Erase Ubuntu ... and reinstall** option with warning. It’s exactly what you need.

[image: Installation type]

I mean *the second* option in this screenshot.

**Alternative**

You can alternatively select *Something else* which shows you all your partitions, then:

1. be careful and don’t do what you’re not sure about;
2. select the Ubuntu partition, on which it’s currently installed;
3. click on change/edit button [I can’t remember the word];
4. set the type as **ex4**, check for **format**, and set **/** as the mount point.

That’s it. This will format your current Ubuntu partition and reinstall everything again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a partition tool to find out how many and which partitions you have. With Windows 7 you will probably have 2 (1 for system and the other for Windows itself).

Partition tools can be Computer Management tool on Windows 7, or Gparted Live iso for example.

After seeing the partitions you should create the partitions where you want to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Looking at it in Partition wizard I have 3 Partitions in my hard drive, one (unlabled) that is FAT, one labled Recovery(NTFS) and one Labled OS (NTFS) then the USB I have been using for ubuntu the live CD. After looking in there and in windows explorer I haven't been able to find any trace of ubuntu. I am aiming to reinstall ubuntu with the dual boot option that was in the installer in the live CD, it had it's own partition slider-thing.

Comment: Yes do that. It appears that you don't have an Ubuntu partition

Comment: That doesn't show up when I boot the live CD, it says I already have two OSes

Comment: Remove the USB, burn a iso into a CD or DVD and try again.

Comment: Ok, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Open Computer Management by clicking the Start button , clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Maintenance, clicking Administrative Tools, and then double-clicking Computer Management.   If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

In the Navigation pane, under Storage, click Disk Management.

There you can see all your partitions and you can delete/format it including the Linux partitions.

Best Advice : Delete the Linux Partition and then extend your Windows partition(by right clicking on the Windows partition).
Boot up Ubuntu and select the option install Ubuntu alongside with Windows. Then you will get a slider to allocate required space for Ubuntu partition. This will make installation much more easier

Comment: There is no Linux Partition, and when I boot Ubuntu, there is no option to install alongside.

Answer (score 0):

I screwed up my first install of ubuntu and decided to start over. I just went into the Windows control panel, add/remove programs, and uninstalled ubuntu. ubuntu went away completely, even in the boot options on the machine, and I re-did the install successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Live-CD or Live-USB, choose Try Ubuntu. Then use the installer, and when you see the options 'Install inside Windows', 'Re-Install Ubuntu', etc, there should be an option 'Something Else'. In that option you should see all the partitions in your Hard Drive.

Another thing you can do to see the partitions is, once in the Live version, open the terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and use:

```
sudo -s
fdisk -l
```

The /dev/sda corresponds to the hard drive, and the /dev/sdaX (where X is a number) represents different partitions.

I guess you don't see the Ubuntu partitions in Windows because they're in a diferent file system (ext2, ext3 or ext4) and Windows recognizes only FAT16 FAT32 and NTFS file systems.

Anyway, in case there are or not Ubuntu partitions, use the 'Somthing else' option to format the existing Ubuntu partitions, or create them if they don't exist.

PS: the Ubuntu version I used is 12.10, maybe other versions don't have this option in the installer...